# asp.net email length validation

Tags: asp.net, regex, email-validation

I'm trying to validate an email with RegularExpressionValidator and i wrote this expression

```html
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail"
    ErrorMessage="INVAILED Email aderss."
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    ForeColor="Red">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but i need to add more thing 
i want the length of the whole email address is 6 character at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your original regex and adding a lookahead to it

`^(?=.{6,})\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$`

allows only 6 or more characters.

```
 ^ 
 (?= .{6,} )
 \w+ 
 ( [-+.'] \w+ )*               # (1)
 @ \w+ 
 ( [-.] \w+ )*                 # (2)
 \. \w+ 
 ( [-.] \w+ )*                 # (3)
 $
```